# Islamic Perspective of AI Consciousness

Tags: religion, artificial-intelligence, consciousness

**Story Premise**

I am writing a short story in which the protagonist believes his android assistant is demonstrating signs of consciousness. The android's mind is based on deep-learning artificial general intelligence and has progressed well beyond human comprehension. My protagonist does not know how consciousness could have emerged and is frightened by the ramifications. He feels the only person he can discuss this with is an old friend and work associate who's opinion he respects.

The largest portion of the story is a dinner conversation in which they discuss the nature and origin of consciousness and the possibility of a soul, in order to decide what must be done with the android. They each bring a variety of perspectives to the conversation. My protagonist is a former Chief Data Scientist now involved in AI for robotics; his dinner partner is also a Data Scientist and entrepreneur. My protagonist considers himself nonreligious with a lingering Christian mindset. His dinner partner is a faithful Muslim.

**My Problem**

I would like to keep the dinner partner Islamic if I can. However, I'm having a difficult time determining the Islamic view on emerging consciousness in AI, and whether consciousness amounts to a soul. There are plenty of papers and discussion threads on the Islamic perspective of whether a machine can have a consciousness or a soul (even here).  But all are based on the premise that the android was *intentionally built* with consciousness. My premise is that consciousness *emerged*. For the nonreligious, it is, therefore, an emergent attribute of the universe. For the religious, God-given.

**My Question**

Is it possible for a contemporary Muslim (within the constraints of his faith) to believe that God would give an android consciousness? We'll leave the question of whether it has a soul out of it since I intend to leave that for the reader to ponder.

Feel free to give me homework.

(P.S., If you think another faith would be more fitting, I'm open to hearing your thoughts).

Comment: There is a Stack Exchange site about [islam.se], have you checked if they would accept your question?

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Indeed here you might get an answer from a worldbuilding perspective, while if you are more interested in the religious perspective, the respective might be more suited

Comment: Welcome to World Building SE.  Your question is interesting and intriguing.  I think it will take a lot of challenging research to find your answer.

Comment: Duplicate of this?  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/69549/reasons-a-future-branch-of-islam-would-be-against-ai

Comment: Are you specifically thinking of more "traditional" versions of Islam or would you include Muslim thinkers who try to synthesize religious ideas with scientific and philosophical ones, like [Mohammed Iqbal](http://www.brownpundits.com/2018/05/09/review-the-reconstruction-of-religious-thought-in-islam/)? In a future scenario it seems possible these kind of reinterpretations would become more mainstream.

Comment: While Islam is nowhere the top of my list of interests, I do know that there multiple theological strains within it, some comparable with classical Christian theology in depth of thought and scholarship, others comparable with Neoprotestantism in fervor and enthusiasm. Moreover, within Christianity, the mainstream apostolic denominations would take a dim view of a lay person expressing theological opinions about the consciousness of androids or any other subject; I don't know how this works in Islam. I doubt that a Salafi and a Wahhabi would have the same opinion, even if both are Sunnis.

Comment: AlexP makes a good point, you need to know a lot more about this Muslim character to write them, you need to know their imam.  I think you could probably do a much better job of writing this character if you engaged the Muslim community and learned from them. Their stack, as previously suggested, is a good starting place, but if you plan for this character to play a bigger role than offering a few opinions maybe joining a muslim web community where outsiders are welcome. Depending on where you live there might even be some sort of meatspace event you could attend.

Comment: What a fascinating question!!  I'm just so very sorry you're planning on writing your MC from such a weak perspective!  His weak "lingering christian mindset" will have absolutely no basis to either form a proper judgement on its own nor properly evaluate his Muslim friend's perspective.

Comment: @Willk No, not a duplicate. But the thread contains a link to what was ultimately my answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**TL-DR the verses quoted in [the question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2320/is-it-haram-to-make-humanoid-robots) render my question irrelevant. Having an Islamic dinner partner is a non-starter for the purposes of my story.**

Thanks, everyone, for all the input.

The first comment that I received (Thank you, John Dvorak) directed my attention to an Islamic board on Stack Exchange. I did some research there before asking, of course, and came up with this thread, [Is it haram to make humanoid robots?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2320/is-it-haram-to-make-humanoid-robots)

I originally chose Islam to honor a past co-worker who's opinion I always respected. I was modeling the dinner partner after him and felt this was a good way to introduce a perspective that differed greatly from my protagonist's. I full well intended to find a Muslim beta-reader, but now I see I can't even make it that far.

Back to the drawing board!

Comment: Hi Mark, You should add this as an edit to your question instead of answering it. It is more comment in nature, that an actual answer.

Comment: It is an answer. The answer is that it could be haram to make a humanoid robot in the first place -- so we don't even get to the question of consciousness. Therefore, I'm going to choose a different alternative perspective for the dinner partner.

Comment: The question was about Consciousness, not making a humanoid robot. I understand that in your scenario, the robot would have never existed and hence for you, the answer is simply no. However the general question, `Is it possible for a contemporary Muslim (within the constraints of his faith) to believe that God would give an android consciousness?` does not ask if creating a humanoid robot is Haram.

Comment: Putting "thanks" at the beginning of an answer makes this look like a thank you answer, which are frowned upon here.

Comment: The answer you got on that thread didn't actually say it was haram to make a humanoid robot, it just suggested it couldn't look *too* close to a human, but that "The degree at which a robot (or any other humanoid form) is considered to resemble Allah's creation is not defined". And the verses cited for the answer were from hadiths, not the Quran, and there is a [significant tradition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism_of_Hadith) of questioning hadiths within Islam. Also note that the hadith mentioned could apply to photographs/movies, which most of the Muslim world is fine with.

Comment: Also see [this page](http://www.understanding-islam.com/the-prohibition-of-pictures-mentioned-in-hadith/) pointing to difficulties in the interpretation of those hadiths when they are compared to other hadiths, and comes to the conclusion "In my opinion, the images and the imaging referred to in the cited narratives are only those, which entailed elements of polytheistic beliefs."

Answer (score 9):

First of all, the Quran seems to state that [animals are conscious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animals_in_Islam) and that therefore they to praise God (Allah), which is why they have to be slaughtered a particular way in order for their meat to be eaten; it is meant as a sign of respect to the animal and as a form of 'sacrifice' on the animal's part to humans.

That does not however answer the question of a soul; it would appear that most Muslims believe that the soul of an animal does not survive the death of the animal, and that the soul surviving death and being received in Heaven is the exclusive domain of humans.

From that perspective, I'm of the view that the most likely interpretation of this occurence would be that the Muslim would indeed believe that the consciousness carries with it the ability to praise God, but that it does not possess a soul, or at the very least, it does not possess a soul that can survive the death of the AI's consciousness. In that sense, it would have all the hallmarks of a very intelligent animal in the eyes of Islam, except for two very important considerations;

**1) Origin of the consciousness**
There is the possibility that a Muslim (or a Christian for that matter) may view a conscious AI as a creation purely of Man, not of God. As such, it could be seen as an abomination as it is attempting to play in a space that has up to this point been the exclusive domain of God.

One interpretation of this could be that Man creates the body and mind, but God gives it the spark of life that makes it conscious. That would be the easiest interpretation in a religious context to work with, but it's just as possible that it could be rejected entirely as a man-made construct attempting to play God, which could be received with hostility. This of course brings us to the most important exception;

**2) Consciousness is not Liveness**
As a researcher in this field, my comments on the nature of AI in terms of consciousness, awareness, and liveness are well and truly on the record in this site and others. Without rehearsing that research once again in its entirety, the practical upshot of it is that you can have a machine that is intelligent, displays awareness and is potentially 'conscious' according to a narrow interpretation of the word, but none of that makes it alive. We tend to conflate ALL these terms because it's only now that we're reaching the point in AI research where it is important to know the difference between them.

Even if a computer is conscious and aware of its own existence, that doesn't make it alive and it doesn't have the same underlying drives we have, like hunger or a survival instinct, to contend with. It will be able to simulate emotions but not feel them. In other words, we do not have to imbue it with the same 'rights' we imbue other living things, especially other people. As such, we can categorically state that it cannot and will never have a soul.

As such, it fails the first test of consideration in terms of religion; it's not alive. It gets all the same level of consideration as a rock or a tool. In point of fact, that's all it is; a very intelligent tool.

While it may be able to fool us otherwise because of the human propensity for anthropomorphism, a Muslim with training in data science and machine learning will know this machine for what it truly is; a machine. As such, I'm not convinced that religion would even come into it. If it did however, I believe that this creation would have a status similar to an animal, provided of course Islam is free to interpret the spark of consciousness as being the sole element God has provided to the project.

I will state for the record however that this is just one possible interpretation of belief from someone who does not practice Islam and is based on my own personal reading of the Quran and other research to further my own understanding.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you're mistakenly using the term "alive" instead of sentient. It is trivial to demonstrate that a non-organic AI will never be alive. That certainly doesn't mean it couldn't be sentient and it certainly doesn't mean we do not need to afford it rights.Perhaps this apparent confusion stems from the fact that there is indeed major overlap between "aliveness" and "sentience". Indeed, many entities which are alive are also sentient (namely animals, including humans), though there are some that obviously aren't (plants for example; on account of their lack of a nervous system). (1/2)

Comment: Certainly we have never yet observed an instance of an entity which is sentient but not alive, though using this as the sole basis to declare it impossible is to fall into the trap of the black swan fallacy. (2/2)

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful and well-informed insights. The idea that we conflate consciousness, liveliness, and a soul is central to the story I'm writing. My protagonist (who had developed an AI limbic system for AGI applications) is conflicted. He argues your very points publicly. But, he questions himself privately because of his and his wive's emotional attachment to the android. His dinner partner (whom my question is about) helps him sort through a philosophic and ethical rat's nest that he's made for himself. I'll take your comments into consideration while working on the second draft.

Comment: "It will be able to simulate emotions but not feel them." wait, isn't it exactly what science in XVIII & XIX century was saying about cats and dogs, explaining why vivisection is ok, and why NASA was ok to electrocute test animals at the beginning of space race? It sounds awfully familiar.

Comment: Jinn and angels are examples of non-human entities that seem to be treated as sentient beings in the Quran, are they thought to be "alive" in the sense you're talking about? If not, that would suggest life isn't seen as necessary for consciousness.

Comment: @Mołot yes it was, but the difference there is liveness. The irony of this view being a resurrection of Descartes is not lost on me but we know dogs feel because they come from a similar provenance to us as biological organisms; computers simply don't and are not alive. Besides, (and I hate to get into this again) if computers are truly sentient as we are, then free will is an illusion because computers are algorithmic in nature and therefore all their decisions can be accurately predicted given perfect knowledge of their inputs.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Jinn and Angels are not human, true, but they're not completely physical either. This is actually a good example of why there's no simple answer on this kind of question.

Comment: @AngelPray While I understand your point, I do respectfully disagree with it. A creature that is sentient but not alive does not necessarily get automatic rights; for one thing it won't have the same need for survival as we do, nor would it 'feel' needs the way we do. This is a very deep question and while I understand and respect your view point I fall down on the other side of the argument; I believe that being alive comes first, then sentience. Not the other way around.

Comment: @TimBII To be clear when I said "[...]it certainly doesn't mean we do not need to afford it rights.", I wasn't making the claim that we do in fact need to give AI specific rights (that's a topic for another day). Whether or not we should give AI any rights is a separate issue to whether or not you have any justification to positively claim that we shouldn't. I hope the distinction isn't lost on you, because I admit, it is a subtle one. (1/4)

Comment: @T On a different point, I have to respectfully point out that your response to Mołot is rather lacking in basic rigor... The notion that two entities cannot have the same properties because they do not share similar origins (I'm sure you can think of many examples where this is not the case) is spurious at best. A trivial example to the contrary, if your view of AI is correct and it is created, both it and humans would share the property of intelligence even though humans and AI are (by your own admission) of different provenance. Clearly this directly opposes your previous supposition. (2/4)

Comment: @T And as for your point AI and freewill… Well, yes, it may be that sentient AI would cast (yet more) doubt on the validity of belief in non-illusionary freewill. But that’s simply not how we reach a more complete understanding of the world. Even if sentient AI and freewill were completely incompatible that still wouldn’t justify dismissing the possibility of the former out of hand. In that case, better to continue denying the heliocentric model of the solar system because it calls into question the cherished illusion that humans occupy a privileged position within the universe. (3/4)

Comment: @T If you follow that reasoning to its logical extent one should base their beliefs on the unique criterion that they affirm a worldview that one already finds appealing. It is precisely because this is such a profound question where a definite answer would have such broad implications on law, ethics, philosophy, religion and society in general, amongst other things, that we should avoid jumping to knee-jerk conclusions based on our personal preferences. Not least when sentience is a phenomenon so poorly understood even by the foremost experts on the topic (whom I am decidedly not among).(4/4)

Comment: @AngelPray these are all good points and I suspect that you and I are in more agreement than these comments may imply. I agree that this is a complex and nuanced subject that is much larger than can fit in an answer field, let alone a comments field. Suffice it to say that my position is not as simple (and has not been formulated that simply) as is defined by the answer or my comments thereto. I'm happy to leave it at 'this is a very deep, complex subject and I'm expressing just a small part of my learnings and conclusions within it'  for now as this always generates debate beyond the question

Comment: @TimBII What is the difference between simulating emotions and "feeling" them? What are emotions if not simple programs on the human brain that make us do this or that thing? I do not understand your distinction.

Comment: @T.Sar I could get into the whole 3 brain model et al if the comments field wasn't so short, but the best small answer I have is that we express emotions which are effectively chemical interactions that disrupt or enhance the electrical processing of our cerebral cortex and influence our actions. A computer simulation can only simulate that and express a behaviour it's programmed to express. A computer won't even *know* whether it's happy or sad, it will just blindly do what it's programmed to do and it's *us* who infer an emotion from that behaviour.

Comment: @TimBII Why do you think so? Just to give a few examples - an ai that doesn't have anything to process (is idling) would feel bored. An AI that has more stuff to work that can fit on its memory (is overloaded) would feel _stressed_. An AI that has its processors always hitting the Optimzation Queues properly (as in, working on data it is used to) wouldn't feel any cognitive dissonance and thus feel comfortable, and so. Emotions aren't just chemicals, they are _state monitors_. The AI equivalent of those would be the readings of its sensors and what it knows about the state it wants to be in.

Comment: @T.Sar a computer that is idling isn't bored; it's idle. It sits there idle until it has something else to do and then does it. It doesn't feel stress or discontent at all and it doesn't *want* to be in any state; it will merely trend towards the state it's programmed to prefer. Emotions aren't state monitors, they're state drivers (push us towards or away from a given state) and computers operate very differently. A difference engine can resolve a complex set of weighted options to be sure, but it isn't driven to by its environment, it's programmed to by an algorithm. That's a big difference.

Comment: @Tim B II - One could also view the laws of physics as an algorithm (there is [good basis](http://www.daviddeutsch.org.uk/wp-content/deutsch85.pdf) for thinking any physical phenomenon could be simulated by a quantum computer algorithm), so our brains would be products of that algorithm. And one could also imagine creating a detailed physical simulation of a brain that had been scanned in sufficient detail, where the simulated neurons would act just like real ones (a "mind upload")--would you be confident it wasn't experiencing boredom or other emotions even if it acted just like a person?

Comment: (cont.) If you think that a simulated person that acted just like a real one wasn't *really* having the same inner conscious experiences (what philosophers call [qualia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualia)), this leads to problems with thought-experiments where you imagine *gradually* replacing the neurons in a person's brain with simulated equivalents, see David Chalmers' paper [Absent Qualia, Fading Qualia, Dancing Qualia](http://consc.net/papers/qualia.html).

Comment: @TimBII “computers are algorithmic in nature and therefore all their decisions can be accurately predicted given perfect knowledge of their inputs.“ - This is a common misconception as algorithms run as computer software only need access to a truly random bit source to make them truly non-deterministic even under complete knowledge of their inputs. A possible source of randomness is some amount of a radioactive substance of which the number of decaying nuclei during clocked  time intervals is measured.

Comment: @collapsar That's actually the common misconception; that doesn't make a computer random; it just provides another source of random input. Computers are algoorithmic, and adding new hardware to introduce randomness is just another input if you truly understand what system theory is and how it works.

Comment: @TimBII Random input is not just another input in this context since its values are not known thus breaking determinism. True, you may tamper with the Hardware and snoop into the bit stream before processing but one can go one step further: By exploiting quantum effects as a source of randomness in a quantum computer, it becomes impossible to know the value of these inputs without unpredictably affecting the algorithmic computations upon them, breaking determinism again.

Comment: This is just wrong. If you know what the randomising hardware's inputs are, you can still predict the outputs. This is a fundamental misunderstanding of system theory that I've explained many times in the past. Besides, I've never designed an ai for such a system and I don't know anyone who has. Even if I had, being able to program free will as a result of introduced randomness just can't happen, all you end up with is an unreliable system, not one with free will. This is just another distraction from the broader question which keeps coming up.

Answer (score 1):

This is a weird question, because you're asking if a religious Muslim would believe that an android would have a consciousness, but not a soul. I suppose that would be a sensible question from an atheist perspective because scientists view the ultimate facility of humanity being its sentience - man's thought processes and logical components. Hence the 'Turing' test - a test that determines whether a machine can perfectly mimic a human's behavior.

The thing is, if you start from a *religious* perspective, (and, to clarify, I'm discussing the Abrahamic religions here) consciousness isn't even a conversation starter. The soul is. And most of the rest of my answer is going to echo Tim B II's second answer - a quote 'freethinking' computer is just an illusion created by a complex program. No program truly has free will or sentience. It's just a tool. Even if the tool is kind of creepy as to how useful it is, it's still just a tool.

Comment: Why do you say all religious people would think "no program truly has free will or sentience"? There is a philosophical perspective called [compatibilism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/compatibilism/) that defines human freedom in a way that doesn't contradict determinism, and there have been [religious variants of this idea](https://www.iep.utm.edu/theo-det/). That article deals mostly with Christian compatibilism but [this article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27643351) argues it's present in some Jewish traditions; as for Islam, see next comment

Comment: (cont.) Islam apparently has a doctrine called [Qadar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predestination_in_Islam) that says all our actions are predestined by divine decree, and that's led to various arguments about how this could fits with the idea of free will, see [here](http://www.bediuzzamansaidnursi.org/en/icerik/divine-determining-qadar-and-free-will-al-irâdah-al-juz’iyyah-according-bediuzzaman’s-works), [here](https://www.whyislam.org/on-faith/destiny-and-free-will/) and [here](https://dialogosphere.wordpress.com/2016/11/01/the-problem-of-pre-determinism-and-its-impact-on-muslim-thought/).