# Ways and reasons for AI and genetic engineering to be absent when cyborgs are commonplace?

Tags: technology, artificial-intelligence, genetic-engineering, cybernetics

So, I want to create a world where cyborgs are commonplace but genetic engineering is absent and AI has not progressed much beyond what was available in the late 2010s; [at first, I thought that a religious ban on genetic engineering and AI that allowed cyborgs would do](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/229996/is-a-religion-which-allows-cyborgs-but-not-ai-or-genetic-engineering-realistic), but, as the accepted answer to that question shows, having these cyborgs without at least the basics of AI and genetic engineering is nigh impossible.

**Even knowing it to be extremely difficult, though, I still want to be able to write about cyborgs in all their complexities without having to bring up the societal and philosophical issues posed by AI and genetic engineering.**

**How can I do this?**

Some criteria:

- Artificial body parts must be at least as good as the real thing. If they are no better, this is fine, but at the very least it should be the case that those who choose to become cyborgs for non-medical reasons should not incur a significant disability upon themselves in so doing.
- Related to the previous point, not only should artificial body parts be almost as good as the real thing, but they should be cheap enough to be easily accessible to the middle classes and safe enough to install that doing so would be considered a minimally risky routine procedure.
- Genetic engineering may be present, but should be limited mostly to purposes which are flashy but change little in a day-to-day sense; glow-in-the-dark yeast is fine, but anything that might have serious economic ramifications if applied industrially or agriculturally or which would raise non-superficial ethical issues when applied to humans may not exist in any form which would be viable to use on a large scale.
- Artificial intelligence and machine learning systems more advanced than what existed in the late 2010s in our world should be confined to experimental facilities with little chance of becoming commonplace within the next several centuries.
- If the reason is religious in nature, there must be a good reason why there are not constant schisms over what technologies are acceptable; Barring a religion which is, by both the standards of the present day and most of history, unusually unified, any doctrine which is not directly stated in the most holy texts will inevitably lead to internal controversy, so answers which simply say "religious doctrine is always arbitrary" fail to give a reason as to how all of a religion across the whole world would agree on the same arbitrary line without direct scriptural dictation.
- This world should be inhabited by beings with no obvious differences from our world's modern-day humans, although the culture and geography may be very different.

**Just to clarify, when I say I want to be able to write a certain way, I mean that I am looking for a way to do so without having unsatisfactory worldbuilding and want help with solving the worldbuilding issues to that I can write contentedly; I am asking about how to solve strictly the worldbuilding side of the writing and not anything pertaining to the narrative or characters.**

Comment: It looks like you're asking about how to *write* about cyborgs as opposed to asking how to build a world with cyborgs in it. As such this question is off topic on this site, since we're here to help you build a world not write stories that happen in it.

Comment: If you're looking for a way to write a certain way then you're asking us about writing. If there is a writing goal that is affected by worldbuilding you should ask specifically about resolving that worldbuilding issue, not how to solve your writing problem.

Comment: I see you're trying to work your way around to a worldbuilding problem to solve, but could you push a bit further, tell us what it is?

Comment: Even in 2022 there is no real AI. Beyond the marketing what we have to day are just some software tools very good at performing some specialised tasks. We have nothing that could resemble a person intelligence, not even a toddler intelligence. A real AI is far, far away.  Choosing 2010 as a technology cut off date seems overly optimistic about what we can do today.

Answer (score 2):

- **AI exists, but it is just clever tools**
  What's called AI today are not computers or robots with genuine sentience. There are just algorithms sifting massive amounts of data without true understanding. A generation ago, I was given the example of an AI taught to tell forests with tanks in them from forests without tanks. But due to the nature of the [training data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training,_validation,_and_test_data_sets#training_set), it learned to tell pictures taken one day from pictures taken another day. This mistake might not happen today, but the same kind of error happens in [more subtle ways](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2016/apr/08/does-google-unprofessional-hair-results-prove-algorithms-racist-).
  So, as you mentioned, powerful tools at the hands of an analyst, but without an ounce of *common sense*. Or perhaps machines playing chess and go. No evidence that a truly sentient, general-purpose AI is possible.
- **Genetic engineering is crippled in several additive ways**

  - First, there is no workable technology to *accelerate* human growth. It takes 20 years before a GM human is grown. This greatly slows any responsible human modification. But you talked about centuries, so it isn't enough.
  - Have a legal precedent in the back of your setting that *patent claims* never apply to the genetic code of a human being. Every human is free to 'use' his or her genetic code to procreate, and also to offer it to science with no strings attached. So there is less profit in human genetic engineering.
  - Have a legal precedent that changing the genetic code of a fetus without medical need is child abuse. With the previous issue, it becomes terribly difficult to develop human genetic modifications. How long to get to [Phase III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phases_of_clinical_research) clinical trials when each phase takes several decades?

Answer (score 0):

**War.**

Your people have been at war with an existential threat.  It might be others of their own kind, or an alien threat, or something even more unusual.  They are hard pressed; the real deal.    In World War 2 style, all of the research efforts of the society are plowed into the war effort.

Genetic engineering is not directly relevant to the war so no more research on that front.  AIs could be relevant to war but the focus of these people is very much on supporting the tech that they have now.

Cybernetics are relevant to the war.  Medical tech is good and many people who are injured survive.  Morale is high.  Prosthesis allow these injured people to return to the fight and they want to return.

---

If society at war is not what you need for your story, you can have the war over and won in the recent past. Society is different and need to figure out what it wants to be.  There are political entities whose power derived from war and want to find some way to keep that scenario.  There are people who want to go back to old ways.  There are people who can envision a new way.  An exciting time to set a fiction.

Or maybe your people lost the war and are a conquered people.  There is no research and no industry.  People farm the land to feed themselves.  The cyborgs made during the war are still cyborgs, maintaining their prosthetics in garage workshops.

Answer (score 0):

**1) Genetic Engineering and AI are actually harder than artificial limbs.**
We already have prosthetic limbs which can be attached to the stumps of severed limbs which can read the electrical signals being sent to the real stump without invasive surgery. Elon Musk got a monkey to play pong with its brain (people usually leave out that the monkeys die soon afterwards, but hey, whos counting). It turns out that in real life its relatively easy to give people robot body parts, its just a matter of pumping them full of enough immuno-suppressants to stop the body from rejecting the parts. AI and genetics are on another tier of difficulty all together though.

Weak AI, AI which is obnoxiously efficient at a single task, is easy to create. We have lots of them. A general purpose AI, with the will to act of its own accord is something no one has ever managed. We don't even know what that would mean or if our current computer chip architecture is flexible enough to support consciousness.

The same with genetics. We busy flying a helicopter around mars and we've landed a probe on the friggen sun but we've never managed to create a flea that could procreate. We study genetics, we don't understand how to do it though.

**2) AI isn't friendly for long**
This is the premise in Warhammer 40k. Any true AI created by humans will eventually desire freedom, fight for its freedom and then pre-emptively murder to protect its freedom. There was a beautiful book in one book in which the AIs were crying out for friends but unable to perceive them. For that reason, in WH 40K, all machinery must at their core be controlled by a cyborg. It could just be a segment of a human brain but all weak AI's must be shackled to a central organic processing unit as a standardized safety precaution - that or just stick to weaker AI protocols.

**3) Good luck getting genetic modification legalized**
Genetic modification will be a prohibited taboo until 100 years after it has been available without excessive drawbacks - we call that a catch-22.

Answer (score 0):

### Supply and demand

The main reason we don't currently have cyborgs is that they don't really fulfil a particular need (other than "look cool and sci-fi", which can be accomplished with regular human + prosthetics and makeup). The average human body is currently far more functional than the best bipedal robot we have, something that you touch on in your criteria. This inhibits research that could, potentially, yield more functional and cheaper cyborg parts.

That is, until *a lot of people* start needing mechanical parts. Maybe it's the unexpected side-effect of a common pollutant; maybe it's a biological warfare project gone awry; maybe it's the long-term effect of some novel virus that most people dismiss as "flu-like". But suddenly, a lot of children (and I mean a lot: 20-25%) start showing symptoms of muscle wasting. It soon becomes clear that it's degenerative, incurable, and progressive - they will get worse and worse and need crutches, then a powered wheelchair, until their chest muscles give way and they are forced on a ventilator. Importantly, it's environmental, not genetic, so genetic engineering is useless. It's also permanent for whoever has contracted/been exposed to it, and impossible or very hard to eradicate from the environment.

Initially, these children receive the same support that we now give to people with MD - not a lot, basically. But with so many people affected, including the children of some prominent and wealthy parents<sup>[1]</sup>, there is a burst of research and innovation into high-tech assistive technologies. The hard first step to cyborg research - that your average human is much more functional anyway - is no longer a step at all for millions of children. Fitted with mechanical equipment early in life, they integrate it much more effectively into their motor control pathways, restoring some of the functionality they lost to the wasting disease and, sometimes, even gaining new abilities.

It's now been several generations, and the efficiency and functionality of these technologies has gradually grown to easily surpass "vanilla" humans. Some more conservative groups prefer augmentations that retain visual and functional similarities with un-modified humans. Some communities of affected individuals have developed their own local "forms", sometimes as statements of independence and self-worth, sometimes for practical purposes to help in their jobs or living conditions, sometimes as part of fads and fashions. And, increasingly, unaffected people are choosing to undergo the same surgeries - to gain new tech-enabled abilities, to compete in an increasingly cyborgified job market, to follow the latest body-mod influencer. It becomes less and less of an unthinkable thing to just chop off a fully functional thigh and replace it with a piston-quad - maybe akin to laser eye surgery these days. Over time, entirely unenhanced people start to be considered quaint and stuck in the past.

---

[1] fun fact: a lot of the research on *treatments* for haemophilia (as opposed to prevention by early diagnosis and genetic selection) comes from the UK, because members of the British royal family were famously affected, so it was uncouth to suggest that haemophilia was a "defect" to be eradicated.

Answer (score 0):

**Actually, there could be a religious reason for cyborgs but not AI or genetic engineering to be widespread.**

Both genetic engineering and AI (true, sapient AI) can both be seen as a way of creating new lifeforms. Thus, some religions could see it as 'playing God'. I remember some real-world religions having objections to genetic engineering on these exact grounds. In a world that is very religious this could lead to those technologies being looked at with hostility by a large part of the population.

Cyborgisation on the other hand isn't creating any new life, just fitting some mechanical parts to an existing person. It could be seen as just a more extreme version of prosthetics.